# Add build framework support to custom new project (intellij plugin development)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing my own intellij plugin that create custom project. This plugin generate important files and add custom SDK, but i need to add build framework support (maven, gradle and ant).

It should look something like that but instead of Kotlin support there should be Maven, gradle and ant.
[in this red section should be these build frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLDEO.png)
User choose one and after choose 'finish' button on the last page it should generate important files like pom.xml or gradle.build etc.

Is there any class in `com.intellij.openapi` that can help me achive this? Any tips what should i do? Is it possible to manually generate the necessary files (pom.xml gradle.build) that IDE "saw" it as maven?

Comment: Basically, the answer is no. If your framework supports Gradle, then projects of this type have to be Gradle projects, not projects of your custom type.

Comment: So in each of Gradle, Maven and Ant build type i should add my template as additional framework?

Comment: Yes. Kotlin does basically that.